# jQuery each iteration problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

```
<section class="photos">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/a"><img src="b.jpg" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="/a"><img src="b.jpg" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="/a"><img src="b.jpg" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/a"><img src="b.jpg" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="/a"><img src="b.jpg" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

And then I am trying to iterate through each  to return the link href and the image src.

```
$(".photos td").each(function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.a.attr('href'));
    console.log(value.img.attr('src'));
});
```

The above pseudo-broken-code doesn't unfortunately work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run jQuery methods on `value`, since it's just a DOM node. Create a jQuery object out of it first (I prefer `this` to the `value` argument, but they're the same in this case):

```
$('.photos td').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).find('a').attr('href') );
    console.log( $(this).find('img').attr('src') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adam already gave the answer, but since I was typing it... try this: (the only difference is in the traversal part, since Adam uses "this" while I use "value" (which are the same).

```
$(".photos td").each(function (index, value) {
    console.log($('a', value).attr('href'));
    console.log($('img', value).attr('src'));
});
```

Don't forget that value represents a dom element (and not a jQuery element), and attr() is a jQuery method that works only for jQuery objects.
Also, shouldn't you be closing your  tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".photos td").each(function (index, value) {
    console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```